# Block until Loader finishes in ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2

Tags: android, android-testing

I am writing an Android Activity test case by extending ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.  The Activity I am testing offloads work to a Loader.  The Activity itself is the LoaderCallback.

The problem is that the test case finishes before the Loader completes its work (because the Loader is obviously running on another thread than the test case).  How can I get the test case to wait until the Loader has finished its work.

One thought I had was to join to the underlying Loader thread. However, I can't seem to find a way to get access to the underlying thread. Also, the Loader thread might not start immediately so not sure this is the right approach.

The other though I had was to register a LoaderListener in the test case, but it seems a particular Loader can only have one LoaderListener.

Comment: Use `Thread.sleep()`, check our the sample code I answered in another similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491526/how-can-i-test-the-result-of-a-button-click-that-changes-the-activitys-view-asy/10491965#10491965).

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing but that seems to brittle. The test could fail simply because the machine running the test is too slow. I want a rock-solid way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a max timeout.  Check for a null value in the loader every so often until you reach the max timeout. Once the max timeout is set have the test fail because the loader would not load.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it with mutex or ReentrantLock.

Comment: Thanks for posting! Could you add some more comments to the code to increase clarity?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some Java synchronization method between the thread the test case is running in, and the background thread or action you are waiting to complete.

I have used a countdown latch.

In your code under test (Activity in my case)

Initialize it when your activity is created

- private final CountDownLatch signal = new CountDownLatch(1);

When the Loader finishes, have your code signal it's done:

- signal.countDown();

I provide a getter for the latch in my code under test

- public CountDownLatch getSignal() {
      return signal;
  }

In your test:

- start the activity (which starts the background thread)

  - MainActivity activity = getActivity();
- get the latch to wait on

  - CountDownLatch signal = activity.getSignal();
- do other stuff, then wait for the background task to end

  - if (!signal.await(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
    fail("Timed out waiting for the background task to complete");
    }

This works for stuff being in done in background threads, AsyncTasks etc that are started by the onCreate() method of your activity...